# Merge Table Cells

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to write a macro to merge cells vertically of a table in Word document.

I found one example

```
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set Rng = .Cell(lv_srow, lv_sclm).Range
    Rng.End = .Cell(lv_erow, lv_eclm).Range.End
    Rng.Cells.Merge
End With
```

This code is working fine for horizontal cells merging, but it is not working for vertical merge(like combing A1,B1,C1 as one cell).

Answer (score 4):

This should work both ways ... you just have to be careful about the `Row` and `Column` reference in `.Cell`. For example

[image: Horizontal]

[image: Vertical]